# How to get the latest GNOME shell in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, upgrade, gnome-shell

I want to try gnome-shell 3.5 but I don't see it in the repos, I'm using Fedora 17, is there any way adding gnome-shell 3.5 to my repos?

Please note the question was asked on Aug 2012. Now I'm using Fedora 18 with gnome-shell 3.6 as on 29th Jan 2013.
What I meant was how to install the latest from gnome-development. I see that as of today GNOME shell 3.7 something is the latest but Fedora has 3.6 in its repos.
That's what my question is about, how to get the latest.

Comment: Do you want the latest or 3.5?

Comment: please note the question was asked on aug 2012. Now i'm using fedora 18 with gnome-shell 3.6 as on 29th jan 2013.
what I meant was how to install the latest from gnome-development. I see that as of today gnome shell 3.7 something is the latest but fedora has 3.6 in its repos.
Thats what my question is about, how to get the latest.

Comment: To get the current (development) version of gnome (i.e. the one from git) you have only one option: [`jhbuild`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Jhbuild/)

Answer (score 1):

> [At this point] GNOME 3.18 is the latest version, released in September 2015. You can try it [using this specific [openSUSE live image](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/GNOME:/Medias/images/iso/?P=GNOME_Next*); follow the instructions below to install it to a USB stick]. -- https://www.gnome.org/getting-gnome/

Alternatively, run the ISO download using your favorite virtual machine software (cough, GNOME Boxes).  Disclaimer: very limited hardware access, including no 3D acceleration for GNOME Shell.

Answer (score 0):

What is in the Fedora repos (particularly update) is the latest. You *might* try [koji](http://koji.fedoraproject.org), where freshly built packages are uploaded. What you find there goes from failed builds through utterly broken packages all the way to the update that is being pushed for distribution right now. Definitely not recommended, but hey, Unix is all about giving the user enough rope to shoot their feet.

You could try Fedora 18, but that one currently has gnome-shell-3.6.2-6.fc18. Or dive into rawhide (rolling updates with the very latest stuff that hasn't exploded on first run).

Comment: please note the question was asked on aug 2012. Now i'm using fedora 18 with gnome-shell 3.6 as on 29th jan 2013.
what I meant was how to install the latest from gnome-development. I see that as of today gnome shell 3.7 something is the latest but fedora has 3.6 in its repos.
Thats what my question is about, how to get the latest.

Comment: The latest gnome can be found at `http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/` Be aware that it has not been tested with Fedora. Have fun